# MariaDB refuse to start after VServer reboot

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

After I rebooted my VServer, MariaDB refuses to start.

This are the error messages:

```
# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-02-18 11:02:39 UTC; 2min 56s ago
Process: 5921 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 6931 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 18 11:02:09 server mysqld[7119]: InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
Feb 18 11:02:09 server mysqld[7119]: InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
Feb 18 11:02:09 server mysqld[7119]: 160218 11:02:09 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
Feb 18 11:02:09 server mysqld_safe[7133]: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Feb 18 11:02:39 server /etc/init.d/mysql[7412]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Feb 18 11:02:39 server /etc/init.d/mysql[7412]: [61B blob data]
Feb 18 11:02:39 server /etc/init.d/mysql[7412]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")'
Feb 18 11:02:39 server /etc/init.d/mysql[7412]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Feb 18 11:02:39 server /etc/init.d/mysql[7412]:
Feb 18 11:02:39 server mysql[6931]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

and

```
# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-02-18 10:10:43 UTC, end at Thu 2016-02-18 11:02:39 UTC. --
Feb 18 11:02:09 server mysqld[7119]: InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
Feb 18 11:02:09 server mysqld[7119]: InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
Feb 18 11:02:09 server mysqld[7119]: 160218 11:02:09 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
Feb 18 11:02:09 server mysqld_safe[7133]: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Feb 18 11:02:39 server /etc/init.d/mysql[7412]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Feb 18 11:02:39 server /etc/init.d/mysql[7412]: [61B blob data]
Feb 18 11:02:39 server /etc/init.d/mysql[7412]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")'
Feb 18 11:02:39 server /etc/init.d/mysql[7412]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Feb 18 11:02:39 server /etc/init.d/mysql[7412]:
Feb 18 11:02:39 server mysql[6931]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

My my.cnf can be found here: https://debianforum.de/forum/pastebin.php?mode=view&s=39158

After searching arround I found the config option "innodb_force_recovery" if I set it to "6" the database server starts but the database is still broken.

Any idea what's the problem here? How could I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I'm not sure if I understand it completely but it seems to be something similar to what is described here https://mariadb.com/blog/get-rid-orphaned-innodb-temporary-tables-right-way I deleted all #sql*.idb and #sql*.frm files and the database server started again. Not sure if this is the perfect solution but it worked.